# AWS API Gateway calls from client side (Javascript)

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am new to [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), so wanted to know. Is it secure to call Amazon API Gateway from Client side, and what kind of security issues may occur. e.g Token replay etc?

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you referring to the AWS API Gateway service that can trigger Lambda functions or pass requests to EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway supports several options for securing your API.  You can use Cognito user pools with AWS SigV4 for maximum security.  Alternatively, API Gateway supports custom authorizers so you can build your own authentication/authorization system using Lambda functions.  If you need something simpler (and less secure), API Gateway also support API keys which are a simple bearer token useful for tracking which applications are calling your API.